# Where is the Dropwizard HealthcheckServlet?

Tags: dropwizard, health-monitoring, codahale-metrics

I have the following in my build.gradle:

```
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:3.1.0"
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlet:3.1.0"
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:3.1.0"
```

On inspection of metrics-servlet, I see:

[image]

According to https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/servlets/,

"The metrics-servlets module provides a handful of useful servlets", including HealthCheckServlet, MetricsServlet, and ThreadDumpServlet.

Where are these Servlets if not in metrics-servlet!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are both a metrics-servlet *and* metrics-servlets module.  Servlet contains abstract framework classes and servlets contains the concrete implementations.

This works:

```
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:3.1.0"
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlet:3.1.0"
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:3.1.0"
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:3.1.0"
```

And actually, only the following is needed:

```
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:3.1.0"
compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:3.1.0"
```